# Is there a C function which calculates process elapsed time?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, elapsedtime

I am trying to learn OS for my class using C and Ubuntu. I could not find any information about calculating elapsed time of a process? Also, i should do this by writing new system call in kernel. Can anybody help me? I couldn't even try a code block because I am looking at the internet for hours. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `time` for the terminal?  Example: `time main.exe`

Comment: It's not possible to know how to help you because your question isn't specific. Do you know how to add a system call? If not, that's what you should ask specifically. If so, you should say so. (There are plenty of tutorials on how to add a system call to the Linux kernel. Use a search engine.)

Comment: Yes, I know how to add system call. I just don't know and can't find how to calculate elapsed time of a running process...

Comment: Check `time()` before and after the process runs and take the difference.

Comment: Do you need wall clock time, or will CPU time suffice?

Comment: What do you mean wall clock time :)  I need process start time
and the current time (process should still be running).

Comment: 'Wall time' is the elapsed time-of-day of a clock, CPU time is shared between processes. Suppose you have 999 other processes running with an equal share of processor time, then one second on a wall clock is only 1/1000 second of CPU time *used by your process*.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Then, I need wall clock time. I just need to calculate difference between start time and current time( because process still running) but I don't know how to do this in a C function.

Comment: @trytobeengineer You have a lot of things to do and it's not clear which you need help with. You say you know how to add a system call. Do you know how to get the process start time? Do you know how to get the current time? Do you know how to subtract two times? Have you looked at existing system calls that get or manipulate times? You won't get a good answer if we don't know specifically what step you're stuck on. If it's the first step, THEN ASK ABOUT THE FIRST STEP.

Comment: There's the question of granularity too. Is `x` whole seconds good enough by using the function `time()`? Function `clock()` gets fractions of a second, and system-specific functions (not standard C) can time shorter intervals.

Comment: You call `time()` at the beginning of the program, save the result in a variable. When you want the elapsed time, call `time()` again, and subtract the original variable from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **clock()** function. It's available in **time.h**.
But since you are using Ubuntu just use time in terminal.

```
g++ "yourfile.cpp" -o file
time file
```

Comment: You cannot execute a .cpp file directly.

Comment: @Clifford Yeah you're right. `g++ "yourfile.cpp" -o file`                                                       
`./file` to execute `time file` to time. This should work then.

Comment: I believe OP is supposed to write a kernel module, not a shell script.

Comment: Also, despite its name, `clock()` returns processor time, not wallclock time.